# JQuery cookie not updating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I have a cookie set by default with the value of false

```
$.cookie('globalLang', 'false', {expires: 2, path: '/'});
```

On button click (`.global`), I want `globalLang` to update to "true".

```
<a href="" class="global">English</a>

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".global").click(function(e) {
      $.cookie("globalLang", 'true');
    });
});
```

However, with the above approach, my cookie isn't updating, it's just creating a new one (I have two `globalLang` cookies, one with the value of false, and another with true).

Reading the [documentation here](https://www.kevinleary.net/jquery-cookies-get-set-update-delete/), I believe I'm doing it right, so unsure why it's creating another?

Comment: They're probably being added to different paths. Pass the same object to the second `cookie` call.

Comment: @BenM - ah, cheers, seems to have done the trick